# Facebook open graph scraper not seeing HTML

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have had trouble getting the Facebook open graph scraper to see my pages or recognize the meta tags on them. SOME of our pages work, (e.g. the book product pages) but most pages do not show any images or correct title info in the debugger. The home page is one I am especially interested in getting Facebook to recognize, but there are many others that do not work. All of our pages show up with a 206 response code in the facebook scraper here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ However, for most pages, I get a blank page when I check the 'what the scraper sees' link. I have also tried scraping just the image URL on the homepage, and the debugger sees the image just fine.

This is the homepage link:
https://press.uchicago.edu/index.html

Here is what the header section looks like:
[image: Homepage head]

There is a redirect from https://press.uchicago.edu/ to the index.html page, but I've been testing using the full link above.

However, the book product pages DO work with the scraper. Such as this one: https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/N/bo125517349.html

And the header tags for the working pages are like this:
[image]

Since I usually see response 200 on other pages I test on the scraper debugger, I have also created a small version of a homepage with JUST the open graph meta tags as a test.  That page can be seen here: https://press.uchicago.edu/index4.html

Here is the entire source of this page:
[image]

Even this small page gives me a response of 206 from the debugger. I think the 206 is probably not related the problem. Facebook support pages say it is OK, but it seems odd that such a small page would give a partial response... so maybe it is part of the problem.

One other thing that was sort of interesting: I tested one page on our site that has no og: tags, and it worked the first time I tried it in the scraper, showing an image and lots of constructed og tags. Plus, it showed me lots of info when I clicked on 'What the scraper sees' link. But subsequent tests of the same page (which hasn't changed at all) in the debugger have been empty images, and a blank page in what the scraper sees. This was that page: https://press.uchicago.edu/books/freeEbook.html

Comment: This is what Facebook sees https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fpress.uchicago.edu%2Findex.html . Nothing. You are not returning any HTML to Facebook. For the product page you return HTML https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fpress.uchicago.edu%2Fucp%2Fbooks%2Fbook%2Fchicago%2FN%2Fbo125517349.html

Comment: Right. I get that, but I do not see what is different between the pages to cause nothing to be sent to Facebook.

Comment: The pages that work don't have the "robots noarchive" meta tag

Comment: The last 2 links I posted also do not have the "robots noarchive". It is only on the home page. But just in case, I removed it from the home page, and the scraper is still not getting anything. The og:type is also different, but I've tried using "book" on the home page, just to test, and it did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: If Facebook can't see anything it is because you don't send anything back to Facebook. I would suggest looking in the logs for your server. Or do the same request as Facebook does and see if you get anything back

Comment: Try and disable the GZIP compression, that can be problematic for the Facebook scraper. (If that solves the issue, then you can go and find a way to only disable it for requests made by the scraper, it can be identified by its user agent.)

Comment: @CBroe Facebook recommends the GZIP compression on their best practices page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

Comment: That might well be, but it is known to have caused problems in the past (https://github.com/dgrammatiko/facebookfix), so you should at least give it a try.

Comment: @CBroe I tried with no gzip and Facebook still could not see the page. But I copied the html from the view source and pasted it into a newcities page, and facebook sees it fine, and pulls the image (from our server), and everything looks great there. It must be something in the server and not the html page. So the tags for this question are probably wrong.

Comment: One question I still haven't been able to answer is if it is the server, how do some pages on the same site get through to Facebook?

Comment: Apparently it was the cache control. We had it as: "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0". But I changed it to just "Cache-Control: no-cache" and Facebook could suddenly see the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the cache control. We had it as: "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0". But I changed it to just "Cache-Control: no-cache" and Facebook could suddenly see the page.

Facebook must need to store a copy of the page, so the no-store setting prevents that.

Here is some more about the settings:

""no-cache" and "no-store"

"no-cache" indicates that the returned response can't be used to satisfy a subsequent request to the same URL without first checking with the server if the response has changed. As a result, if a proper validation token (ETag) is present, no-cache incurs a roundtrip to validate the cached response, but can eliminate the download if the resource has not changed.

By contrast, "no-store" is much simpler. It simply disallows the browser and all intermediate caches from storing any version of the returned response—for example, one containing private personal or banking data. Every time the user requests this asset, a request is sent to the server and a full response is downloaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#directives